# Circle Detection in python in real time using open cv

Tags: python, opencv

I was working on this project with motion detection and then i came across a need to identify an object
But me being noob at this all image processing thing

can you show me source code for circle detection in VideoCapture() function of python opencv (mostly houghcircles)

p.s. plz don't give the code for circle detection in image in need to detect it in video that i'm currently taking through webcam

Comment: a video is just a sequence of images, so if you know how to detect a circle in an image and if you know how to load a video and process its frames, you will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

C++ code for circle detection in a video

```
 #include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
    #include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
    #include<vector>
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;
    int main()
    {
        Mat img;
        Mat thresh;
        VideoCapture cap(0);
        vector<Vec3f>circles;   
        for(;;)
            {
                cap>>img;
                cvtColor(img,img,CV_BGR2GRAY);
                GaussianBlur(img,img,Size(5,5),2,2);//smoothing reduces false positives
                threshold(img,thresh,130,255,THRESH_BINARY);
                HoughCircles(thresh,circles,CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,2,img.rows/5,200,100);
                cvtColor(img,img,CV_GRAY2BGR);
                for(int i=0;i<(int)circles.size();i++)
                {
                    Point center=Point((int)circles[i][0],(int)circles[i][1]);          
                    int radius=(int)circles[i][2];              
                    circle(img,center,radius,Scalar(255,255,0),4);
                }
                imshow("img",img);
                imshow("thresh",thresh);
                char c=waitKey(10);
                if(c=='b' || c=='B'){
                    break;  
                }
            }
        return 0;
    }
```